# Spacy, noun phrases: How to locate noun phrase span start and end token of every noun_chunk in doc with spacy

Tags: nlp, token, spacy, chunks, phrase

I am using spacy to get the noun phrases of a text.
What I want to do is locate those noun phrases in the text with respect to the token index of the words.

For instance

```
import spacy

# Load English 
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("The blue car is nicer than the white car"
noun_chunks = list(doc.noun_chunks)

for i,noun_chunk in enumerate(noun_chunks):
    for j,token in enumerate(noun_chunk):
        print(i,noun_chunk,j,token.text)
```

The value j is an index of the token.text within the span of the noun chunk, but I want to get the token.i number of the first and last word of the noun_chunk

In the example the two noun chunks are:
"the red car" 
and
"the white car"

the desired output would be:

tokens:
The 1
blue 2
car 3
is 4
nicer 5
than 6
the 7
white 8
car 9

noun chunk 1: "the blue car"; starts 1, ends 3

noun chunk 2: "the white car"; starts 7, ends 9

with the start and end of a noun chunk I will be able to identify the span of the noun chunk in the doc

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know about the start and end method of a chunk

chunk.start gives you the start token number of the chunk span
chunk.end gives you the end token number of the chunk span